# Cygwin not same python version as windows

Tags: python, cygwin

Background:

I am a .NET developer trying to set up a python programming environment.

I have **installed python 2.7.5**. However I changed my mind and **uninstalled 2.7.5** and installed python 2.7.6.

If I CMD in windows command promopt, the python version is 2.7.6

When I start the cygwin shell and type:

python --version

It says 2.7.5, this version is was uninstalled.

How do I get cygwin to understand it should use the new version. 2.7.6?

I believe there is commands to type in cygwin shell to solve this? Thanks on advance!

Comment: `echo %PATH%` in CMD to see which python version is being pointed at, `export` that path in cygwin as well

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, mind giving an example of how the export command looks like in cygwin?

Comment: export, thank god Im used to windows CMD!

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:<path-to-python>` in your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: So I do cd my way to the file where ~/.bashrc is, then export?

Comment: It's a text file, just open it and insert that line, or if the line exists, edit it.

Comment: All right flawless! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin has its own option to install its own version of Python. If you run `setup.exe` and poke through the Development packages, you'll find it. You probably installed Python here as well, and are running it in Bash. If you use CMD, you're running a different version. The fact that the version numbers overlap is just coincidental.